# Records not retriving as decimal precision lost when getting grouped records

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

We have a project using Linq to SQL. After grouping, the records are not selected from the tables which is related to the group Key. Running the profiler helped to find out that the condition added while retrieving the records have a lesser precision for the decimal field. What is the solution for this?

```
var  groupedSO = from so in db.SalesOrders
                 orderby so.BizDate, so.POSID ascending
                 where SalesOrders.Contains(so.POSID)                                                
                 group so by 
                 new
                 {
                     so.BizDate.Value.Date,                                                      
                     so.CurrRateMultp, //Decimal: Value in DB is 0.33333333                                                        
                 }
                 into grps
                 select grps;
```

When we loop through the groups,

```
 foreach (var orders in groupedSO)
  {
    foreach (var order in orders)
      {
        //No records available
      }
  }
```

it selects the records using SQL similar to

```
select <Fields> 
from Table 
where CONVERT(DATE, [t0].[bizdate])  = @P0 AND  @x4 = [t0].[currratemultp]
```

but value of @x4=**0.3333** in the SQL generated, while in DB the value is **0.33333333**

This causes the record not to be retrived.

The field is mapped in a simple way

```
[Column]
public decimal? CurrRateMultp { get; set; }
```

The field type in SQL is

```
decimal(19, 8)
```

Please help what changes needed to add the precision.

Comment: You can use decimal.Round(number,3) or something similar in your query

Comment: Where does the value that gets assigned to `@x4` come from?  Where is the code that creates that SQL when you _loop through the groups_?  Also what is the exact type of the `CurrRateMultp` column in the DB?

Comment: Check database to see what the type is.  It looks like the database is a double and the C# is a single which doesn't make any sense.  The C# decimal type is 96 bits.  So I suspect that the database is a nvar (which is a string) and there is a conversion from the string to a single being made in the interface in the Net Library.

Comment: Please check edits. @VinayPandey I need the exact value what is stored in DB, here i am just reading the information.

Comment: @juharr The SQL i traced from profiler. the value for 'x4' is from the group Key formed by Linq.

Comment: @jdweng , please check the edit made for the DB type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all those checked this,

I figured it out. There is a Named Parameter [DbType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.columnattribute.dbtype(v=vs.110).aspx) for the [ColumnAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.columnattribute(v=vs.110).aspx). Even though Microsoft site says

> Use this property to specify the exact text that defines the column in
> a Transact-SQL table declaration. **Specify the DbType property only if**
> **you plan to use CreateDatabase to create an instance of the database**.
> The default value of DbType is inferred from the member type. For more
> information, see SQL-CLR Type Mapping.

Setting this to the SQL type helps me to get the precision.
so, I declared my property as

```
 [Column(DbType = "decimal(19, 8)")]     
 public decimal? CurrRateMultp { get; set; }
```

This made the SQL to generate with the rite number of decimals.
Thanks all! Hope this help someone else too.